# How do I subclass UISegmentedControl so that individual segments recognize a UILongPressGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uisegmentedcontrol

First off [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464649/is-it-possible-to-differentiate-between-a-long-press-and-a-tap-on-a-button) has been helpful in my understanding of how to subclass UIButton for long presses. I would like to do the same for UISegmentedControl, however I don't see how I would be able to identify which segment was held down since UISegmentedControl does allow direct access to it's segments (UISegmentedControl.h shows them as private). I could just customize a few UIButtons to look like an UISegmentedControl however I would also have to implement the momentary switch logic. Which wouldn't be a big deal but subclassing UISegmentedControl seems cleaner to me.

BTW, I'm using this control to imitate a radio's preset controls: tap to go to a saved station and hold to assign the current station to that segment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this without subclassing and it seems to work.

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer* recognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pressGesture:)];
recognizer.delegate = self;
[mySegCtrl addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
[recognizer release];

...

-(void)pressGesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    NSLog(@"pressGesture %@", gesture);
}
```

Long press first selects the segment then fires the gesture.  If you aren't getting the callback check my code - I got stuck for a while because I wasn't setting recognizer.delegate=self.