# UIButton touch and hold do animation, when released, the animation stops

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, uibutton

I am trying to do a animation when the user is touch and holding the button, when the touch is released, the animation stops. How to do that?

Comment: amy try with ** UILongPressGestureRecognizer**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464649/is-it-possible-to-differentiate-between-a-long-press-and-a-tap-on-a-button

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284792/uibutton-touch-and-hold

Answer (score 2):

Try this

**Add TouchDown ,Touch Up Inside, Touch Up Outside event to ur button**

[image]

```
-(IBAction)theTouchDown:(id)sender
{

[self startAnimation];

}
-(IBAction)theTouchUpInside:(id)sender
{

[self stopAnimation];

}
-(IBAction)theTouchUpOutside:(id)sender
{

[self stopAnimation];

}

-(void)startAnimation
 {
 //write your logic
 }

-(void)stopAnimation
 {
 //write your logic
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to implement the below method

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //Start your animation
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   // stop your animation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `Touch Down` and `Touch Up Inside` and `Touch Drag Outside` features for UIButton.

Create two methods for starting and ending animations.  Map Start animation method to `Touch Down` and  Stop animation method to `Touch Up Inside` and `Touch Drag Outside` sent events.

Since the user can drag the finger from the UIButton to outside. It will work fine.

[image]